# PCIe Gen 5.0 specification register figure drawings - dotted lines Vs solid lines

Tags: cpu-architecture, pci-e

[image]

above is an example of a figure from PCIe Gen5.0 specification. here some bit locations are marked with dotted green line Vs some are marked with solid black lines.

While spec defines all bit fields and all figures, i could not find purpose behind these lines.  Do they mean anything? if no,why the spec has two different line markings. if yes, can you help me identify meaning of it.?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

The line styles don't have any meaning. They are just to distinguish the lines visually so it is easier to trace a field name to the corresponding bit position.

In every diagram, the line styles are always in pairs, alternating two green and two black, starting with green for the rightmost field.